# Create a loop that calculates (max date-min date) for every unique id and then calculates their mean for every month

Tags: r, loops

in the df below, there are id's and dates. I would like to calculate for every id the average max date minus min date for every month.

```
df
    structure(list(user_id = c("6897bea62278", "6897bea62278", "13d51bc5b108", 
    "8012f20570b5", "5bc61ba43a08", "13d51bc5b108", "13d51bc5b108", 
    "6897bea62278", "8012f20570b5", "13d51bc5b108", "13d51bc5b108", 
    "6897bea62278", "13d51bc5b108", "13d51bc5b108", "8012f20570b5"
    ), date = structure(c(18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 
     18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687
    ), class = "Date")), row.names = c(2L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 
    23L, 27L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 45L, 51L, 55L), class = "data.frame")
```

desired output

```
| Month    | Avg days       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| March    | 23             |
| April    | 15             |
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to test with one days data but is this what you are after?

```
df %>%
  mutate(month = months(date)) %>% #get month
  group_by(user_id, month) %>%
  mutate(xx1 = max(date)-min(date)) %>% #by user and month find range
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(Avg_Days = mean(xx1)) #average ranges by month
```